# Compute Engine and NodeJS, keep online

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssh, sails.js, google-compute-engine

I have a website already developed with node.js and [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) on "Compute Engine" but to start it, necessarily I have to write "node app.js" in the SSH console of browser. But there is a problem (since I am new to Linux and Google Cloud :)), if I want my Node app it keep online, the SSH window must be open, if I close, the Node application will terminate, like Ctrl+c. So it makes no sense to have my computer turned on, just to have the active window. So, how to keep my NodeJS app online without being in the presence of SSH console?. I know the question is illogic to some, but I would appreciate if you help me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

First of all it is not related to Compute Engine nor Node.js.

You mention that the application will terminate if you press `ctrl+c` and that's correct because you are running your application in the **foreground** instead of **background**. To run your application in the background you can either launch your app like this:

```
node app.js &
```

Or you can launch with `node app.js` and then press `ctrl+z`.

But just sending the application to the background wouldn't help. As soon as you disconnect from your ssh session, all programs started (background or foreground) will receive a HUP signal, in node.js  you can handle that signal but the default [behaviour is to close](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_exit):

> On non-Windows platforms, the default behaviour of SIGHUP is to terminate node

One thing that you can do to ignore the SIGHUP signal is running your app as follows:

```
nohup node app.js &
```

If you do this, your application will continue to run even when you close your ssh session. Another way to achieve this is by using the `screen`.

This will help you on very early stage and for development but I don't recommend using neither of these things for production. Eg: if your application crash it should be restarted. The recommended way is to use a service manager that comes with the OS: upstart, systemd, init, to name a few.

Comment: I've been finding out for hours and came to the conclusion module **forever**, and I solved my concern, I running forever app.js start, the application is in the background. Again, thank you very much

Comment: Yes, forever is another solution, but I will encourage you to use what it comes with the OS already.

Comment: `forever` at least ensures that if the process crashes, it will restart. It has a few other features as well

Comment: Yes, like any other service manager that comes by default with the distros. What is going to keep forever running? And how do you run it when GCE reboot your VM?

Comment: forever keeps itself running using container processes. That's why it's called `forever`. Except it's designed specifically to manage node.js processes. This is something you can easily research yourself.

Comment: I know forever and I have used it before. My suggestion is still to use what it comes with the OS, eg: upstart, for two simple reasons: 1- This is what you will use to start/restart/stop any other service in your system, why have two different things. 2- You still will need upstart/init etc to start forever when it crash or when the system is rebooted. Search "forever cron", "forever upstart". You can write an upstart script in 10 lines. https://gist.github.com/jfromaniello/6d051d894d73056d99e9

Answer (score 3):

You can install **forever** module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to your Google compute engine using SSH window.

```
npm install forever -g
```

Then, in your node server directory, execute your server using forever.

```
forever start [YOUR_SERVER_FILE.js]
```

Now, if you close the SSH window, your node server is still on !!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be using a module called forever: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

You can use it this way: 
forever start your_script.js